# Identify the streams from launching multiple rtp streams using gstreamer and janus

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer, janus

I currently have an use case that to do multiple streamings at the same time from an external tool like gstreamer or ffmpeg. I have done some researches to understand how plugin and janus api works, and I have also found a documentation for streaming.

https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/docs/streaming

There is only one RTP port for video input. Multiple listeners are allowed to listen a specific stream, then the question is that how do I differentiate between each streamer? Or I am thinking in a wrong way.

Comment: You just add multiple streams to Janus config file. Every stream will have unique ID and unique RTP port.

Comment: Look to example Janus config file: https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway/blob/master/conf/janus.plugin.streaming.jcfg.sample.in#L136 you just will have multiple similar blocks in your config.